# Show pep8 errors as you type in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, autopep8

I just successfully installed autopep8 in Jupyter and I am able to use hot keys and/or click the gavel to correct cells.  However, I was really hoping that I would see pep8 errors/suggestions as I typed, so that I could learn proper code formatting.

I have the box "Show alerts for errors in the kernel prettifying calls" clicked to True, but I do not see any squiggly lines or error messages - nothing to indicate that autopep8 is checking the cell in real time.  What should I be looking for or is there an extra step I may have missed?

Comment: Could https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp help?

Comment: This looks helpful for other needs.  Thanks.  Does it also make pep8 suggestions?

Comment: Yes if you install appropriate plugin for pyls.